# How to get into another collections with foreign keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dust.js

I have these collections (`books`,`book_genres`,`genres`,`books`)
my `book` `Schema` is like that

```js
var bookModel = function () {
    var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        author_id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Author",
        },
        title: String,
        description: String,
        cover: String,
        likes: Number,
    });
    return mongoose.model("Book", bookSchema);
};

module.exports = new bookModel();
```

I'm using `dust` templating and I'm rendering that collection data on my layout like that

```html
    {#books}
             <div class="large-4 small-12 columns book">
                <div class="row img-row">
                <img src="{.cover}" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <h3 class="small-12">{.title}</h3>
                  <h4 class="small-5 columns ">{.author_id}</h4>
                   <h4 class="small-7 columns ">{.name}</h4>
                </div>
               
                   <div class="row p-row">
                    <p class="small-12">{.description}</p>
                   </div>
             </div>

     {/books}
```

my `author` `Schema` is like that

```js
var authorModel = function () {
    var authorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
    });
    return mongoose.model("Author", authorSchema);
};
```

I want to be able to reach to `author` `name` so I can render it on my layout through the `author_id` that I'm getting from the `book` `Schema` (for sure the `id` in the authors collection is the same as the `author_id` in the `books` collection)

I tried to search for some solutions but no one was using `dust` templating so I wasn't able to figure that out

Comment: [`"$lookup"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) should be useful here.

Comment: "I have these collections (books,book_genres,genres,books)" - this looks more like a design for a relational SQL database rather than a smart NoSQL design, you may review it. Typically the number of collections in a NoSQL database like MongoDB is much less than the number of tables in according RDBMS. Some NoSQL databases even do not support joins at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to resolve the `Author` reference:

```
bookModel.find({}).populate('author_id').exec();
```

You should then be able to access the referenced user fields with:

```
<h4 class="small-7 columns ">{.author_id.name}</h4>
```

In your case, you should change your code to:

```
module.exports = function (router) {
  router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Book.find({})
      .populate('author_id')
      .exec(function (err, books) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        var model = { books: books };
        res.render('index', model);
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: So where specifically to add that "populate" line of code ? I'm sorry but I'm a beginner at node stuff

that's how I'm finding the book model in the main page by that controller 
module.exports = function (router) { router.get("/", function (req, res) { Book.find({}, function (err, books) { if (err) { console.log(err); } var model = { books: books, }; res.render("index", model); }) }); }

Comment: You saved my life 
I'm unable to describe how thankful I'm